# How to force DataGridView to re-populate its rows using IQueryable<TEntity>

Tags: c#, entity-framework, gridview, datagridview

```
BlaEntities TestContext = new BlaEntities();
IQueryable<TestEntity> Entities = TestContext.TestEntity;
TestDataGridView.DataSource = Entities;
```

When I assign Entities to TestDataGridView's DataSource directly; I don't have to do anything to reflect my changes to the grid.

```
TestEntity entity = Entities.First();
entity.Title = "What up!?";
```

This is more than enough to see the change in the TestDataGridView. One exception I encountered was that if I add another row to the TestContext using `TestContext.AddToTestEntity(...)` , it doesn't show up in the grid (contrary to deleting it) but I got it working using the BindingSource's Add method.

```
BindingSource source = new BindingSource{DataSource = Entities};
TestDataGridView.DataSource = source;
source.Add(CreateNewTestEntity());
```

Now the only obstacle left in my way is this:
If I use filtering - like `TestContext.Where(t => t.Active)` - use it as DataSource to my grid, then change the first record's Active property to false, how do I refresh/reload the grid to reflect this without creating another instance of BlaEntities?

```
IQueryable<TestEntity> FilteredEntities =
    TestContext.TestEntity.Where(t => t.Active);
TestDataGridView.DataSource = FilteredEntities;
TestEntity temp = FilteredEntities.First();
temp.Active = false;
```

I see it is not active anymore in grid but since the grid should show only the active records, how can I remove it from the grid without removing it from the source?

- When I iterate over `FilteredEntities`, I can see that the `temp` isn't there anymore but I still can see and edit it in the grid. So what I need is something forces grid to iterate its DataSource (which is FilteredEntities) as well and populate itself again
- I tried calling `TestContext`'s `Refresh` method and `BindingSource`'s reset methods.
- I tried changing `TestDataGrid.DataSource` to `null`, then changing it back to `FilteredEntities` hoping to re-populate the rows, didn't work either.
- It works if I save my changes using `TestContext.SaveChanges()` and use another instance of `BlaEntities` like `TestDataGridView.DataSource = new BlaEntities().TestEntity.Where(t => t.Active)` but I need to use my current instance.

So the question is, how can I make the TestGridView to reload its contents using FilteredEntities.
Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>since you already have a `BindingSource` have a look at the [ResetBindings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.resetbindings.aspx) method</strike>

//edit:
as from the comments below:

i would approach this problem with a factory for "Entities" ... if that factory would hold a ref to the last created IQueryable, it could implement the interface IQueryable itself, by forwarding all interface methods to that created object ... so it could act as a wrapper for your datasource that can replace that datasource by recreating it based on the predicate function and the actual state of all objects

Comment: Thanks but I already tried it, as I mentioned in the question. It doesn't remove the row from the grid.

Comment: let me ask a dumb question ... you handle some event to call ResetBindings ... which one did you choose?

Comment: A Button's Click event. I click it after I change the selected record's Active property to false. It doesn't matter wheter I change it programmatically or using the grid. I see that the row is not there if I inspect the BindingSource or underlying IQueryable but it doesn't disappear from the grid unless I don't call the DeleteObject method of the ObjectContext or Remove method of the BindingSource.

Comment: what happens if you create a new iqueryable from the same context?

Comment: It works, thanks. But I send the IQueryable<T> (named Entities) and an Action<T, S> (named OnClick) to my generic grid form. I use Entities as grid's DataSource and call OnClick when a user double-clicks a record. I send the selected object and the BindingSource I use as parameters to the OnClick. So if I send a filtered IQueryable and the user changes the row in OnClick in a way that causes the record not to fit the filter, I need that record removed from the grid. Sorry for not specifying that before, I thought the details of the test project I created are enough to explain my situation.

Comment: i would approach this problem with a factory for "Entities" ... if that factory would hold a ref to the last created IQueryable, it could implement the interface IQueryable itself, by forwarding all interface methods to that created object ... so it could act as a wrapper for your datasource that can replace that datasource by recreating it based on the predicate function and the actual state of all objects

Comment: Yes, that beats it. Could you edit the answer so I can accept it?